# cannot hydrate "owns" collection property in POJO using neo4j ogm 2.0.6, spring boot, and remote NEO4J Community server 3.1.1

Tags: java, neo4j, spring-data-neo4j, neo4j-ogm

Can not hydrate "`owns`" collection property (annotation property) in a simple `POJO`. the `owns` property comes back empty.

I'm using neo4j ogm 2.0.6, spring boot, and remote NEO4J Community server 3.1.1.

**NEO4J cypher query to populate db :**

```
CREATE (n:Entity { name: 'Bank of A', fid: '100' })

CREATE (n:Entity { name: 'Bank of B', fid: '200' })

MATCH (boa:Entity{fid:'100'}), (bob:Entity{fid:'200'}) 
                            CREATE (boa) -[:OWNS]->(bob);
```

**In the controller :**

```
Entity entity = session.load(Entity.class, neo4jId, 1);
return entity.getOwns();
```

Set of Entities should contain an instance of '`Bank of B`' but returns empty set :

```
@NodeEntity
public class Entity {
    @GraphId Long id;
    private String name;

    @Relationship(type="OWNS")
    private Set<Entity> owns;

    public Entity() {
        this.owns = new HashSet<Entity>();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Needed to pass -1 as the 3rd argument to make relationships load eagerly.
Entity entity = session.load(Entity.class, neo4jId, -1);